# Android Studio bug with dark mode, some things change, others no

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-darkmode

My app has an activity for appearance with a switch to turn dark mode on or off. However, when I change the theme, sometimes it changes everything correctly and sometimes it changes just a few activities or just a few fragments.

Here are some examples of what happens in the same activity with and without the bug:

[The image off the bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAqhs.png)

Here's the code I use to turn on or off dark mode when the switch button is turned on or off

```
   fun activatedDarkMode() {
        if (SharedPreferencesUtil.getDarkMode(this)) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your main Theme's parent is as following:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    ...
</style>
```

Check if this post might help you:
https://proandroiddev.com/implementing-dark-theme-in-your-android-application-ec2b4fefb6e3